# Call Web Service from Servlet

Tags: java, web-services

Since I am newbie to web services . I have started developing a simple application which has a login page and have to do its simple validation

For this I created a simple web service which is used for login validation, I have its WSDL link and created the Client...

Now I wanted to use this on my JSP page..Following are the steps I used,

1. Created the Login JSP
2. When Submit button is clicked the Servlet is called
3. This servlet calls the web service by calling its stub and then the respective method(Note: I had included the service and the client jar in my classpath  n this is how i get the service)

IDE used : Eclipse Indigo
Server : Tomcat v7
Also using Apache Axis 2 Server

I wanted to ask IS THIS THE CORRECT WAY OF CONSUMING WEB SERVICES USING JSP n SERVLETS..or is their any other way out?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this approach. When you start build a full fledged app you may want to create some layers. Otherwise it fine.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no problem if you are calling the web service in Do-post or do Get method with the parameters you got from your HTML form..you can proceed there based on  your web service response.

The only change is instead of connecting to database in servlet you are contacting webservice.